# Cascading Report via Hierarchical Grouping or Subqueries

Tags: sql-server-2012, crystal-reports, nested, hierarchical-grouping

I have a table called 'Materials' (SQL Server 2012) that has two columns (among others) called **PartNo** and **SubPartNo**. This table contains all the parts required to build various assemblies.

For example...

[Material Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgZby.png)

- A PartNo contains at least one SubPartNo.
- If the SubPartNo also contains parts, then the SubPartNo is listed
  in the PartNo column for each SubPartNo it contains.
- This will continue on for as many parts that the assembly contains.

I am trying to create a report in Crystal Reports 2016 that will look something like this...

[Bill of Material Report Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ittg.png)

I tried using Hierarchical Grouping in Crystal Reports but can only get it down to one level of "sub parts". I tried nested SQL statements but I don't know how to store the results of each select statement to "build" my table/results as the statements are processed.

I hope I have explained this clearly enough and would greatly appreciate any assistance you can offer be it via Crystal Reports or SQL statements.